# How To Solve Change Value From Data Excel To MySQL On Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

data excel like image below

[data_excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkURR.png)

i want to change value when upload data from Excel to MySQL

if the cell has the name 'UNSIL' then when stored in the database will change to number '1'

i have code for uploading data from Excel to MySQL on laravel

```
public function importExcel(Request $request) {
    if($request->hasFile('import_file')) {
        $path = $request->file('import_file')->getRealPath();
        $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {})->get();
        if(!empty($data) && $data->count()) {
            foreach($data as $key => $value) {

                if($value->nama_universitas = 'UNSIL') {
                    $value->nama_universitas = '1';
                } else if($value->nama_universitas = 'UNPAD') {
                    $value->nama_universitas = '2';
                }

                $insert[] = ['nama_fakultas'=>$value->nama_fakultas,
                             'nama_universitas'=>$value->nama_universitas,
                             'keterangan'=>$value->keterangan
                            ];
            }
            if(!empty($insert)) {
                DB::table('fakultas')->truncate($insert);
                DB::table('fakultas')->insert($insert);   
                return redirect('fakultas');
            }
        }
    }
    return back();
}
```

in the code above contains the data upload command from excel to mysql, and when I want to change the value of the name 'UNSIL' to number 1 it work but when value name 'UNPAD' and change to '2' it not work.
i use code logic like below

```
if($value->nama_universitas = 'UNSIL') {
                        $value->nama_universitas = '1';
                    } else if($value->nama_universitas = 'UNPAD') {
                        $value->nama_universitas = '2';
                    }
```

Did i miss something, why when name of 'UNPAD' cant change to '2' when stored in MySQL

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31gBL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if-statement should be evaluating the comparison, not setting the value.

E.g.

```
if($value->nama_universitas = ‘UNPAD’)
```

Becomes

```
if($value->nama_universitas === ‘UNPAD’)
```